# Add row totals to tbl_summary

Tags: r, summary, gtsummary, tbl

I am attempting to add row totals to my `tbl_summary()`.

Here is my code so far

```
ibrary(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(q=runif(n, min=45, max=85),
                  r=runif(n, min=2.4, max=6.0),
                  s=runif(n, min=24, max=60),
                  t=runif(n, min=0.28, max=1.73),
                  time=1)

patient <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                      treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
                      age=sample(18:80, n, replace=TRUE),
                      sex = factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4))),
                      smoke=factor(sample(c("Never", 'Former', 'Current'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.25, .6, .15))),
                      bmi=runif(n, min=16, max=45))
df <- cbind(patient, dat)

df %>% select(q, treat, smoke) %>% 
  tbl_continuous(variable = q, 
                 by = treat,
                 include = smoke) %>% add_n()
```

Is anyone able to assist with this last step. I think my issue is where to place the `add_n()` call. I have been using previously made `gt_summary` tables for guidance but something is not working this time.

Much appreciated everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a straight-forward way unfortunately. But you can do it with the code below

```r
ibrary(tidyverse)
#> Error in ibrary(tidyverse): could not find function "ibrary"
library(gtsummary)
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(q=runif(n, min=45, max=85),
                  r=runif(n, min=2.4, max=6.0),
                  s=runif(n, min=24, max=60),
                  t=runif(n, min=0.28, max=1.73),
                  time=1)

patient <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                      treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
                      age=sample(18:80, n, replace=TRUE),
                      sex = factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4))),
                      smoke=factor(sample(c("Never", 'Former', 'Current'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.25, .6, .15))),
                      bmi=runif(n, min=16, max=45))
df <- cbind(patient, dat)

tbl1 <- 
  df %>% 
  select(q, treat, smoke) %>% 
  tbl_continuous(
    variable = q,
    by = treat,
    include = smoke
  ) %>%
  bold_labels()

tbl_row_total <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(all_true = "Total") %>% 
  tbl_continuous(
    variable = q,
    by = treat,
    include = all_true
  ) %>%
  bold_levels() %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>% dplyr::filter(row_type %in% "level")
  ) %>%
  modify_column_indent(columns = label, undo = TRUE) 

tbl_stack(list(tbl1, tbl_row_total)) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Control**, N = 476 | **Treat**, N = 524 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **smoke** |  |  |
| Current | 61 (53, 74) | 64 (57, 73) |
| Former | 66 (58, 76) | 64 (53, 75) |
| Never | 63 (54, 75) | 65 (53, 74) |
| **Total** | 64 (55, 75) | 64 (54, 74) |

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Daniel D. Sjoberg an elegant solution as always. Any way to get the row totals for Current/Former/Never?

Comment: You can repeat the `tbl_continuous()` without the `by=` argument, then merge the tables with `tbl_merge()`.